# How can I pass dynamically component in another component in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have an empty generic form-dialog-component and I want to use it to display another specific forms in a dynamic way without statically putting the selector of another form

this is my form-dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { DataEditionMode } from 'src/app/constants/enum';

@Component({
selector: 'app-form-dialog',
templateUrl:  './form-dialog.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./form-dialog.component.css']
})
export class FormDialogComponent implements OnInit {
 dataEditionMode:DataEditionMode
 editedInstance:any
 component:any
 tagName:any

 constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
  public matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<FormDialogComponent>) { 
   this.dataEditionMode = data["dataEditionMode"];
   this.editedInstance = data["editedInstance"];
   this.component=data["component"]; //Contain the name of my specific form (DemandeFormComponent OR CommandeFormComponent ...)
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 cancel() {
  this.matDialogRef.close({
   "status": "canceled"
  });
 }
}
```

this is my form-dialog.component.html

```
<div [ngSwitch]="component">
    <app-form-demande   *ngSwitchCase="'DemandeFormComponent'" ></app-form-demande>
    <app-form-commande   *ngSwitchCase="'CommandeFormComponent'" ></app-form-commande>
</div>
```

i don't want to use ngSwitch and write the selector of every form...

Any ideas to do it dynamically?

Comment: Checkout ViewContainerRef https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a dedicated component for that purpose which looks like this:

```
export class ComponentHostComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @Input()
  set component(component: any) {
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    if (component) {
      const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
      const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }
  }
}
```

You can apply this component in your template like this

```
<app-component-host [component]="component"></app-component-host>
```

I created a minimal stackblitz on how to do this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ogjs95. Note that it is mandatory to add the  components created with the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to the `entryComponents` array of your `AppModule`.